# Set the parent of an EMF EObject

Tags: eclipse-emf

Consider two EObjects, both created through some factory method

```
EObject parent = instantiateAParent();
EObject child = instantiateAChild();
```

I want `child`'s parent to be `parent`. Is this possible to do this without relying on the exact type of `child` and `parent`? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. What you want to do is the following:

- Retrieve the type (in the Ecore sense) of the parent (parent.eClass())
- Find all its EReferences with isContainment to true (eClass.getEAllContainments())
- Among these containment references, you want to find at least one whose type is compatible with the type of child (eReference.getEReferenceType().isInstance(child))
- Since you may have several containment references at this point, you may use any algorithm to select one (maybe asking the user, etc.)
- Set the value of the reference you chose (parent.eSet(eReference, child)). Note that if the containment reference you chose is single-valued, this may have a significant impact on your model.